# Do you know of any formula to calculate the difficulty score of Sudoku?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, puzzles-games

I am looking for a formula to measure the difficulty level of a Sudoku solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [Pelánek (2011)](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/FLAIRS/FLAIRS11/paper/download/2517/3077)<sup>1</sup>, Sudoku difficulty evaluation was investigated across four existing metrics. These are based on incidences of various logic techniques (see [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)). Results based on Spearman's correlation coefficient are given in Table 1.

Evaluation of difficulty through dynamical systems has [also been explored](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0370.pdf)<sup>2</sup>. In this setting, one considers the association between the difficulty of a Sudoku puzzle and the system's chaotic behaviour. The result is obtained by solving a coupled system of two differential equations after converting the Sudoku satisfiability problem into conjunctive normal form.

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Pelánek, R. (2011). Difficulty rating of sudoku puzzles by a computational model. In *Twenty-Fourth International FLAIRS Conference*.</sub>

<sub>[2] Ercsey-Ravasz, M., Toroczkai, Z. (2012). The Chaos Within Sudoku. *Scientific reports.* 2(1):1-8.</sub>